# Two text views together with variable spacing

Tags: android, xamarin, textview, android-linearlayout

I have two textviews and a LinearLayout.

I want to put these two textviews in the left.

For example:

aaaaaaa 3000

aa 201

aaaa 352

aaaaaaaaaaa 1000

I searched but I could not do it.

EDIT:

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aa"
            android:id="@+id/textViewAbandonE"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="19sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3000"
            android:id="@+id/textViewAbandonER"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="19sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your code and what you want to show!

Comment: share what you have done?

Comment: What problem are you facing? What have you tried and what are the results that you got and how do you want them to be different? Please be specific.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to show what it currently looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the weights you are using on TextViews. Here is how you can do it.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start"
        tools:text= "one"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        tools:text="111111111111"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your **[LinearLayout_orientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#LinearLayout_orientation)**

**Use this**

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

**Instead of this**

```
 android:orientation="vertical"
```

> **`1. android:orientation="horizontal"`** will stack them  as a row. it  allows your elements within the Layout to be placed beside each other

**Sample Example of `android:orientation="horizontal"`**

```
View1 View2 View3 ......
```

> **`2. android:orientation="vertical"`** will stack them  as a column.  it  allows your elements within the Layout to be placed as stack

**sample Example `android:orientation="vertical"`**

```
View1 
View2 
View3
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
       <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewAbandonE"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                         android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAbandonE"
                        android:id="@+id/textViewAbandonER"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">


                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```